# MotionLayout: How to animate content inside?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

Let's imagine we have a tinder - cards that we can swipe away. Let when we drag the card to the left, it rises and decreases in size (for example, scale = 0.7)

When the card is reduced in size, the picture is cropped. Is it possible to make it proportionally smaller and not cut off? (the picture is not a direct descendant of MotionLayout: MotionLayout -> MaterialCardView -> ConstraintLayout -> ImageView (this picture))

Answer (score 0):

Motion layout won't help you solve this problem. Motion layout works with flatten layouts, you have an hierarchy `MaterialCardView` -> `ConstrainLayout` -> `ImageView`.

You have some options here:

1. if MaterialCardView is derived, you will receive callback in [onSizeChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) after that you can change image's size using `View.layoutParams.height` and `View.requestLayout()`.
2. If MaterialCardView is't derived, you can add View.[addOnLayoutChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#addOnLayoutChangeListener%28android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener%29) and do the same.
3. Or you can calculate target height of your card and start animation to it using Animators.

Use `scaleType = ScaleType.FIT_CENTER` on scaled image and look at `adjustViewBounds`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the size with transform api's  android:scaleX android:scaleY (which just scales the rendering of the view not the view itself)